# Pelican's newpost outputs to wrong location

Tags: makefile, pelican

I'm following [this guidance](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/wiki/Tips-n-Tricks#make-newpost) to `Make` markdown to Pelican blog posts.  The guidance says `make newpost NAME='testx'` will output to `./content/pages`, but my files are just going to `./content`.

The script appears to use the PAGESDIR variable for output directory, initialised as: `PAGESDIR=$(INPUTDIR)/pages` where INPUTDIR is `$(BASEDIR)/content`.

The `pages` directory does exist in `content`, with permissions `drwxr-xr-x` (same as `content`).

Any idea why this isn't working in practice?  This is my Makefile script:

```
PY?=python3
PELICAN?=pelican
PELICANOPTS=

EDITOR ?= atom

BASEDIR=$(CURDIR)
INPUTDIR=$(BASEDIR)/content
OUTPUTDIR=$(BASEDIR)/output
CONFFILE=$(BASEDIR)/pelicanconf.py
PUBLISHCONF=$(BASEDIR)/publishconf.py

FTP_HOST=localhost
FTP_USER=anonymous
FTP_TARGET_DIR=/

SSH_HOST=localhost
SSH_PORT=22
SSH_USER=root
SSH_TARGET_DIR=/var/www

S3_BUCKET=my_s3_bucket

CLOUDFILES_USERNAME=my_rackspace_username
CLOUDFILES_API_KEY=my_rackspace_api_key
CLOUDFILES_CONTAINER=my_cloudfiles_container

DROPBOX_DIR=~/Dropbox/Public/

GITHUB_PAGES_BRANCH=master

DEBUG ?= 0
ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
    PELICANOPTS += -D
endif

RELATIVE ?= 0
ifeq ($(RELATIVE), 1)
    PELICANOPTS += --relative-urls
endif

help:
    @echo 'Makefile for a pelican Web site                                         '
    @echo '                                                                       '
    @echo 'Usage:                                                                   '
    @echo '   make html                        (re)generate the web site          '
    @echo '   make clean                          remove the generated files         '
    @echo '   make regenerate                    regenerate files upon modification '
    @echo '   make publish                      generate using production settings '
    @echo '   make serve [PORT=8000]              serve site at http://localhost:8000'
    @echo '   make serve-global [SERVER=0.0.0.0]  serve (as root) to $(SERVER):80   '
    @echo '   make devserver [PORT=8000]          start/restart develop_server.sh   '
    @echo '   make stopserver                    stop local server                '
    @echo '   make ssh_upload                    upload the web site via SSH        '
    @echo '   make rsync_upload                upload the web site via rsync+ssh  '
    @echo '   make dropbox_upload                upload the web site via Dropbox    '
    @echo '   make ftp_upload                    upload the web site via FTP        '
    @echo '   make s3_upload                      upload the web site via S3         '
    @echo '   make cf_upload                      upload the web site via Cloud Files'
    @echo '   make github                        upload the web site via gh-pages   '
    @echo '                                                                       '
    @echo 'Set the DEBUG variable to 1 to enable debugging, e.g. make DEBUG=1 html   '
    @echo 'Set the RELATIVE variable to 1 to enable relative urls                   '
    @echo '                                                                       '

html:
    $(PELICAN) $(INPUTDIR) -o $(OUTPUTDIR) -s $(CONFFILE) $(PELICANOPTS)

clean:
    [ ! -d $(OUTPUTDIR) ] || rm -rf $(OUTPUTDIR)

regenerate:
    $(PELICAN) -r $(INPUTDIR) -o $(OUTPUTDIR) -s $(CONFFILE) $(PELICANOPTS)

serve:
ifdef PORT
    cd $(OUTPUTDIR) && $(PY) -m pelican.server $(PORT)
else
    cd $(OUTPUTDIR) && $(PY) -m pelican.server
endif

serve-global:
ifdef SERVER
    cd $(OUTPUTDIR) && $(PY) -m pelican.server 80 $(SERVER)
else
    cd $(OUTPUTDIR) && $(PY) -m pelican.server 80 0.0.0.0
endif


devserver:
ifdef PORT
    $(BASEDIR)/develop_server.sh restart $(PORT)
else
    $(BASEDIR)/develop_server.sh restart
endif

stopserver:
    $(BASEDIR)/develop_server.sh stop
    @echo 'Stopped Pelican and SimpleHTTPServer processes running in background.'

publish:
    $(PELICAN) $(INPUTDIR) -o $(OUTPUTDIR) -s $(PUBLISHCONF) $(PELICANOPTS)

ssh_upload: publish
    scp -P $(SSH_PORT) -r $(OUTPUTDIR)/* $(SSH_USER)@$(SSH_HOST):$(SSH_TARGET_DIR)

rsync_upload: publish
    rsync -e "ssh -p $(SSH_PORT)" -P -rvzc --delete $(OUTPUTDIR)/ $(SSH_USER)@$(SSH_HOST):$(SSH_TARGET_DIR) --cvs-exclude

dropbox_upload: publish
    cp -r $(OUTPUTDIR)/* $(DROPBOX_DIR)

ftp_upload: publish
    lftp ftp://$(FTP_USER)@$(FTP_HOST) -e "mirror -R $(OUTPUTDIR) $(FTP_TARGET_DIR) ; quit"

s3_upload: publish
    s3cmd sync $(OUTPUTDIR)/ s3://$(S3_BUCKET) --acl-public --delete-removed --guess-mime-type --no-mime-magic --no-preserve

cf_upload: publish
    cd $(OUTPUTDIR) && swift -v -A https://auth.api.rackspacecloud.com/v1.0 -U $(CLOUDFILES_USERNAME) -K $(CLOUDFILES_API_KEY) upload -c $(CLOUDFILES_CONTAINER) .

github: publish
    ghp-import -m "Generate Pelican site" -b $(GITHUB_PAGES_BRANCH) $(OUTPUTDIR)
    git push origin $(GITHUB_PAGES_BRANCH)

.PHONY: html help clean regenerate serve serve-global devserver stopserver publish ssh_upload rsync_upload dropbox_upload ftp_upload s3_upload cf_upload github

## make newpost function

# https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/wiki/Tips-n-Tricks

PAGESDIR=$(INPUTDIR)/pages
DATE := $(shell date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
SLUG := $(shell echo '${NAME}' | sed -e 's/[^[:alnum:]]/-/g' | tr -s '-' | tr A-Z a-z)
EXT ?= md

newpost:
ifdef NAME
    echo "Title: $(NAME)" >  $(INPUTDIR)/$(SLUG).$(EXT)
    echo "Slug: $(SLUG)" >> $(INPUTDIR)/$(SLUG).$(EXT)
    echo "Date: $(DATE)" >> $(INPUTDIR)/$(SLUG).$(EXT)
    echo ""           >> $(INPUTDIR)/$(SLUG).$(EXT)
    echo ""           >> $(INPUTDIR)/$(SLUG).$(EXT)
    ${EDITOR} ${INPUTDIR}/${SLUG}.${EXT} &
else
    @echo 'Variable NAME is not defined.'
    @echo 'Do make newpost NAME='"'"'Post Name'"'"
endif

editpost:
ifdef NAME
    ${EDITOR} ${INPUTDIR}/${SLUG}.${EXT} &
else
    @echo 'Variable NAME is not defined.'
    @echo 'Do make editpost NAME='"'"'Post Name'"'"
endif

newpage:
ifdef NAME
    echo "Title: $(NAME)" >  $(PAGESDIR)/$(SLUG).$(EXT)
    echo "Slug: $(SLUG)" >> $(PAGESDIR)/$(SLUG).$(EXT)
    echo ""           >> $(PAGESDIR)/$(SLUG).$(EXT)
    echo ""           >> $(PAGESDIR)/$(SLUG).$(EXT)
    ${EDITOR} ${PAGESDIR}/${SLUG}.$(EXT)
else
    @echo 'Variable NAME is not defined.'
    @echo 'Do make newpage NAME='"'"'Page Name'"'"
endif

editpage:
ifdef NAME
    ${EDITOR} ${PAGESDIR}/${SLUG}.$(EXT)
else
    @echo 'Variable NAME is not defined.'
    @echo 'Do make editpage NAME='"'"'Page Name'"'"
endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace INPUTDIR with PAGESDIR in newpost recipe:

```
newpost:
ifdef NAME
    echo "Title: $(NAME)" >  $(PAGESDIR)/$(SLUG).$(EXT)
    echo "Slug: $(SLUG)" >> $(PAGESDIR)/$(SLUG).$(EXT)
    echo "Date: $(DATE)" >> $(PAGESDIR)/$(SLUG).$(EXT)
    echo ""           >> $(PAGESDIR)/$(SLUG).$(EXT)
    echo ""           >> $(PAGESDIR)/$(SLUG).$(EXT)
    ${EDITOR} ${PAGESDIR}/${SLUG}.${EXT} &
else
    @echo 'Variable NAME is not defined.'
    @echo 'Do make newpost NAME='"'"'Post Name'"'"
endif
```

Comment: Seems I should be using the `newpage` function!